# Output array keys with a certain key value into a new array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder if there is a function to accomplish the following in a clean and "out of the box" PHP way, so there is no need to create a foreach loop with a conditional in it.

I have an array of objects like e.g.:

```
Array
(
    [1072] => Array
        (
            [a] => True
            [b] => False
            [c] => False
            [d] => True
        )

    [1067] => Array
        (
            [a] => False
            [b] => True
            [c] => False
            [d] => False
        )

)
```

And I wanted to transfer only the array keys with a value of false to a new array that i get something like:

```
Array
(
    [1072] => Array(b,c)
    [1067] => Array(a,c,d)
)
```

**Update:**

My initial solution I tried to prevent before i've posted the question was the following. I've performed a `foreach` loop, within i've checked for each keys value. If the value was equal to `False` i've used `array_push` to append that specific array key to the new results array.

A briefer and more compact solution is the following line i've found when i've discovered `array_keys`:

```
$results = array_keys( $thearray, "False" );
```

It outputs only the keys of an given array `$thearray` with the value `False`.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with an [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is probably a good starting point

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: @MarkBaker Hey, didn't OP reached the goal (what he wanted) with this?! I mean the poster is like electricity  he searches/chooses the way with the lowest resistance to get to his goal/answer. But if you think of that: If you give a kid everything what they want, but the kid doesn't have to do anything, they won't learn what it means to work or what *value* different things have. So if we look at this on SO: If you just do the work for others without them even doing something, they will come back more and more and they will never learn to try/do something by themselves, don't you think too?

Comment: @MarkBaker I mean the first thought is great to help others, but if you think about the results what you produce with this, that people won't even bother to edit, try or do some attempts, they will just post crap and hope that someone does their work and if they got what they wanted they are gone, but they didn't learned anything.

Comment: Sorry for the a bit broad unspecific question and the delayed reply. I am new with PHP, and was trying and searching my way through the functions. :/ Still a bit lost.  @rizier123 i've tried a foreach and within checked with an if statement if the values are equal to false and then used an array_push to add it to the results array. But that is the thing i tried to prevent. Meanwhile i think i've found an acceptable way after going on looking. Just  `$results = array_keys( $thearray[ $index], "False" );` seems did the trick.

Comment: @markbaker thanks i'll take a look at array_walk. array_filter i've taken a look at but stumbled across the callback function and haven't got it working. but i think i give it another spin for learning. thanks and sorry to you too. :/

Comment: @rpk ^ **EXACTLY!**, this is what we want to see! Include such things in your question, say that you tried a foreach, say that you looked at array functions in the manual. <- Because with this we see where you are stuck, so that we can show you how to solve the problem, where you did the mistake, we can give you useful links to read further! (But without this we don't see where you stand with your knowledge, what you don't understand or where you are confused, so it's essential just to put your attempts in your question, no matter if they failed)

Comment: @rizier123 Yep i know. But i've forgotten all my good manners and practices over the course of the last hours struggling switching between the editor and the PHP documentation in Dash. And the array list isnt't the shortest. Anyway will keep in mind and won't happen again.

Comment: @rpk You can still edit your question and add what you did: - foreach, - functions which you looked at in the manual, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I go through each innerArray with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then I filter all values out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which are true and then I just return everything)

```
<?php

    $arr = array_map(function($v){
        return array_filter($v, function($v){
            return !$v;
        });
    }, $arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1072] => Array
        (
            [b] => 
            [c] => 
        )

    [1067] => Array
        (
            [a] => 
            [c] => 
            [d] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: mhhh thanks. But one question regarding your solution. The callback function you use here i've stumbled across in `array_filter` already. in the documentation the callback function is normally externalized. by writing it directly into the array_map and array_filter parameters you just have to write the return values directly into the function like you did? But the sample isn't working in my testscript yet. Have to play around a bit more.

Comment: @rpk If you write the function directly into `array_map()`/`array_filter()` you create an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) this is only available for php >= 5.3, so if you do `echo phpversion();` you will see which version you have. If you have a version less than that you can simply declare the functions outside and just pass the function name as strings to `array_map()`/`array_filter()` instead of the anonymous functions (Also here you can see how I tested it: http://3v4l.org/KUcYY)

Comment: ahhhh i've had a small syntax error for my array definition in the sample script. That was the reason for the error. My php is >= 5.3 . And thanks about the headsup regarding the anonymous and outside functions. Thanks!